# No such column in active record where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
Match.where(approval: {summoner_id: 18})
Match Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "matches".* FROM "matches" WHERE "approval"."summoner_id" = ?  [["summoner_id", 18]]
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: approval.summoner_id: SELECT "matches".* FROM "matches" WHERE "approval"."summoner_id" = ?
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: approval.summoner_id: SELECT "matches".* FROM "matches" WHERE "approval"."summoner_id" = ?
```

But if I do

```
Approval.first.summoner_id
Approval Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "approvals".* FROM "approvals"  ORDER BY "approvals"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
#=> 18
```

It shows up.

I am trying to find all Matches where the Match's Approval has a specific Summoner id.

How do I search this?

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :approval
end
```

Comment: From now on, please tag your questions about rails `rubyonrails` instead of `ruby`. There are lots of Ruby people that don't want rails questions in their feeds.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to reference a column in the `approval` table:

```
:approval => { summoner_id: 18 }
```

but you're making two mistakes:

1. The table is called `approvals`, not `approval`.
2. You're not JOINing it so there is no `approval` or `approvals` table available to your query.

I think you mean to say:

```
Match.joins(:approvals).where(:approvals => {summoner_id: 18})
```

Comment: Ah, "2.2.0 :010 >   Match.joins(:approvals).where(:approvals => {summoner_id: 18})
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'approvals' was not found on Match; perhaps you misspelled it?" -- Match has just one Approval

Comment: Then perhaps you want to `joins(:approval)` instead of `:approvals`.